# What postgres operator should be used for comparing arrays/integer with arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an `Event` model with a jsonb column for `visibility_constraints`. A record usually contains four arrays `included_users`, `included_teams`, `excluded_users` and `excluded_teams`. An `Event` has a visibility of public or private.

Also created indices for the four arrays:

```rb
CREATE INDEX visibility_constraints_included_teams_on_events ON events USING GIN ((visibility_constraints->'included_teams'))
```

Create event

```rb
Event.create(summary: 'Test', visibility_constraints: { included_users: [1, 2, 3], included_teams: [1, 2], excluded_users: [4, 5, 6], excluded_teams: [3, 4] })
```

```rb
=> #<Event:0x00007fc99d8f9670
 id: 1,
 summary: "Test",
 starts_at: Sat, 11 May 2019 21:00:00 CEST +02:00,
 ends_at: Sat, 11 May 2019 22:00:00 CEST +02:00,
 visibility: "vis_private",
 visibility_constraints: {"included_users"=>[1, 2, 3], "included_teams"=>[1, 2], "excluded_users"=>[4, 5, 6], "excluded_teams"=>[3, 4]}>
```

Now I try to retreive events where the `current_user.id` is in `included_users`…

```rb
Event.where("visibility_constraints -> 'included_users' ? :user_id", user_id: current_user.id.to_json)

(0.4ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (visibility_constraints -> 'included_users' ? '1')
```

… or where `current_user.team_ids` is in `included_teams`.

```rb
Event.where("visibility_constraints -> 'included_teams' ? :team_ids", team_ids: current_user.team_ids.to_json)

 (0.5ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (visibility_constraints -> 'included_teams' ? '[3,5,1]')
```

These queries always return nothing so I'm wondering what I might do wrong. Did I forget something somewhere? Use a different operator (Well, I tried but nothing changes)?

Thanks for your help!

---

**EDIT**

\d public.events

```sql
+------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Column                 | Type                        | Modifiers                                            |
|------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------|
| id                     | bigint                      |  not null default nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass) |
| summary                | character varying           |                                                      |
| description            | text                        |                                                      |
| starts_at              | timestamp without time zone |                                                      |
| ends_at                | timestamp without time zone |                                                      |
| allday                 | boolean                     |                                                      |
| created_at             | timestamp without time zone |  not null                                            |
| updated_at             | timestamp without time zone |  not null                                            |
| aasm_state             | character varying           |                                                      |
| visibility             | visibility                  |  default 'vis_private'::visibility                   |
| stage_id               | bigint                      |                                                      |
| visibility_constraints | jsonb                       |  not null default '{}'::jsonb                        |
+------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_events_on_stage_id" btree (stage_id)
    "index_events_on_visibility_constraints" gin (visibility_constraints)
    "visibility_constraints_included_teams_on_events" gin ((visibility_constraints -> 'included_teams'::text))
    "visibility_constraints_included_users_on_events" gin ((visibility_constraints -> 'included_users'::text))
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_cb489a462e" FOREIGN KEY (stage_id) REFERENCES stages(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "availabilities" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_6d29de0e36" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id)
    TABLE "assignments" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_6a5328b71e" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id)
    TABLE "resource_allocations" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_2958f606d4" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id)

Time: 0.048s
```

---

**EDIT 2**

`SELECT * FROM events`

```
+------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | summary   | created_at                 | updated_at                 | visibility_constraints                                                                                          |
|------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 3    | event 3   | 2019-05-15 00:24:50.699237 | 2019-05-15 00:24:50.699237 | "{\"included_users\":[1,2,3],\"included_teams\":[1,2,3],\"excluded_users\":[4,5,6],\"excluded_teams\":[4,5,6]}" |
| 4    | event 4   | 2019-05-15 00:24:55.487215 | 2019-05-15 00:24:55.487215 | "{\"included_users\":[1,2,3],\"included_teams\":[1,2,3],\"excluded_users\":[4,5,6],\"excluded_teams\":[4,5,6]}" |
| 5    | event 5   | 2019-05-15 00:26:15.872433 | 2019-05-15 00:26:15.872433 | "{\"included_users\":[2,3],\"included_teams\":[],\"excluded_users\":[],\"excluded_teams\":[]}"                  |
+------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the user_id to a keyword argument doesn't help much in your case. What you can do is wrap it within `[]` and convert it to JSON.

Using the "contains" operator you can check if *the left JSON value contains the right JSON path/value entries at the top level?*:

```
Event.where(
  'visibility_constraints @> ?', { included_users: [current_user.id] }.to_json
)
```

Which generates:

```
SELECT "events".*
FROM "events"
WHERE (visibility_constraints @> '{"included_users":[<current_user_id_as_integer>]}')
```

Comment: It is generating the query but the result is still empty. I also changed the `included_users` to just [1] in the record to see if it looks for an exact match. Still empty. Any idea what else I could check why this is not returning anything?

Comment: Did you check with the same query? How do your records look like?

Comment: This is the query it generates (current_user.id is 1):

`SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (visibility_constraints @> '{"included_users":[1]}')`

This is the record:

`=> #<Event:0x00007fc99d8f9670
 id: 1,
 summary: "Test",
 starts_at: Sat, 11 May 2019 21:00:00 CEST +02:00,
 ends_at: Sat, 11 May 2019 22:00:00 CEST +02:00,
 visibility: "vis_private",
 visibility_constraints: {"included_users"=>[1, 2, 3], "included_teams"=>[1, 2], "excluded_users"=>[4, 5, 6], "excluded_teams"=>[3, 4]}>`

The record is also is the question.

Comment: Can you describe your tables and paste the result?

Comment: It's in the edit of the question. Is the events table enough?

Comment: Can you share a repo of your project? A workable reproducible example? I guess it'd be easier to work with.

Comment: https://github.com/foamer/jsonb It's not the project but I could recreate the behavior.

Comment: Maybe is a problem with your Postgres version. I'm running 11.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Had it on 9.5., just upgraded to 11.3. Still the same issue. I also ran the query directly on the database and it still returns nothing.

Comment: I created one event record, the one from your question, and worked with that. What data in the database are you trying with?

Comment: Added it to EDIT 2

Comment: There's, you're storing the visibility_constraints columns as text (strings). Try creating a new record in the rails console with one of those values but using JSON.parse. Something like `Event.create(summary: 'Test 3', visibility_constraints: JSON.parse("{\"included_users\":[4,5,6],\"included_teams\":[4,5,6],\"excluded_users\":[7,8,9],\"excluded_teams\":[7,8,9]}"))`.

Comment: That was the nudge in the right direction! Looks like the storext gem I use to cast types somewhere else always converted it to a string. After removing it it works like expected. Thank you so much for bearing with me :)

Comment: That's great. Glad to help, I'll edit the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby but there are basically two ways you can do that.

The preferred way is using containment operator `@>` instead, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT '{"included_users":[1, 2, 3]}'::jsonb AS visibility_constraints
) AS events
WHERE events.visibility_constraints->'included_users' @> '[2]'::jsonb;
```

If that's not feasible using the framework of choice, here's an alternative:

```sql
SELECT events.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT '{"included_users":[1, 2, 3]}'::jsonb AS visibility_constraints
    ) AS events,
    -- lateral function correlated to entries of "events"
    jsonb_array_elements(events.visibility_constraints->'included_users') AS included_users
WHERE included_users::integer = 2;
```